# R - Predicting using the arimax funciton of the TSA package

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit a transfer function model using R in order to apply the fitted model to a validation set of data, because SPSS doesn't allow me to (or I don't know how to) compute point forecasts just like the function `Arima()` from `forecast` package does. It does let me apply the model, but it does not use the dependet variable's lagged values, that's why I am trying R.

Anyone know how I could get those type of "updated" or validation forecasts using the `arimax()` function? I am not looking for the following type of predictions:

```
predict(vixari011, n.ahead=12)
```

But rather these:

```
Arima(test$VIX, model = vixari)
```

From what I have been reading there is no prediction function for the `arimax()` function, any ideas about how I could forecast to evaluate point-by-point performance? I can just think of computing manually using a spreadsheet...

Comment: `predict{stats}` should be able to predict for ARIMAX models. An alternative is `forecast{forecast}`- are you familiar with that function and package?

Comment: @Miguel M. a great answer is given here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/how-to-fit-an-arimax-model-with-r

Comment: @MattSandgren @Learner Yes, you are both right but addressing different things that what I am looking for... what i am actually trying to do is to apply the TF model to some validation/test data in order to check the prediction error (that's why I mentioned the `Arima(test, model=arima)`). Basically I am trying to apply my fitted ARIMAX to data, rather than getting actual forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I know this post is old but this can help someone.

I used this it worked just fine

`forecast(fitted(arimax_ts_model), h=11)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).